# closesocket hangs

Tags: sockets

I've been debugging for days and I have finally found something.

My code for some reasons is blocking in `closesocket()` forever.

Thats the reason all my IOCP threads were slowly dying...

The debugger is showing that `closesocket()` call is frozen in 
`NtWaitForSingleObject(0xXXXX, 0, 0);`

The socket in question is a UDP socket.

The UDP thread which managed that socket has been force closed by `TerminateThread()`.

Is there any reason for this to happen and anyway to fix?

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64

Language: C++ (With Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: What do you mean by 'force closed'? And 'the UDP which managed that socket'?

Comment: Sorry i meant to say "the UDP thread".

Comment: What do you mean by "force closed"?  If you're killing a thread rather than allowing it to exit cleanly, you'll risk doing so when the socket holds a critical section.  This would account for your hang on close - no other thread would ever be able to aquire any critical section associated with the socket.

Comment: Ok so thats the case then and i cant really allow myself to 'wait' for the thread to exit cleanly since it would delay customers on the network.
Is there anyway to cancel all recv/send calls so the thread will stop calling them and THEN kill the thread?

Comment: The real question here is why does the thread need killing?

Comment: As that virtual room is no longer needed and i need it to shutdown immediately.

Comment: Interesting reading here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192800 ... - especially the section referring clean-up.

Comment: Enabling linger and calling shutdown() seem to fix it.