# Function closesocket() freezes for few seconds for UDP socket when the network is down

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, udp, winsock2

Here is a simplified version of the code I am using. Just creating UDP socket, sending something and closing it:

```
SOCKET sock;
sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );
sendto( sock, sMsg, sMsg.GetLength(), 0, iAddr, iLen);
closesocket( sock );
```

It works fine while network is up, but when the network is down, function closesocket() freezes for a few seconds. What it can be and how to resolve it?

I am running Win7 and compiling wih VS6

Comment: Duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870709/closesocket-hangs

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2013/10/09/udp-closesocket-takes-upto-5-seconds-to-return-in-disconnectremote-host-down-scenario-due-to-pending-data-to-send/